# How to get magento data on the wordpress blog page?

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I have integrated WordPress into the Magento for the Blog. Now, I want to display Magento products from the specific category on the blog page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the Fishpig extension, you should just be able to add them using shortcodes
e.g.

```
[product id="4"]
[product ids="4,8,12,16"]
[product sku="your-product-sku"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer myself.

Step1: I created a php file on the root folder.

Step2: Get products from the specific category.

Step3: Call the file in the WordPress homepage.

```
<?php 
$theme_root = get_theme_root();
$theme_root;
$path = '/var/www/html/headsupfortails/blogrelatedproduct.php';
include($path);
?>
```

Step4: override mage/core/functions.php

change the code:

```
function __()
{
    return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate(func_get_args());
}
```

to

```
if(!function_exists('__'))
{
function __()
{
    return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate(func_get_args());
}
}
```